# Writing to and reading from a text file - C# Windows Universal Platform App Windows 10

Tags: c#, text

********IT WORKS! But you have to type in the TextBox before anything shows. I guess that's because I used the 'TextChanged' event handler. Which event handler do I use if I want it to show the contents of the text file without user interaction?********

So I want to write some data to a text file in a C# Windows 10 Universal Platform App when a button is pressed, and I want a TextBlock or a TextBox to read the contents of that text file in my app.

I'm using a pivot-style app, the button to write the file is on one pivot and the TextBlock or TextBox I want to contain the contents of the text file is on another pivot.

My code is below. It doesn't work. I'm not sure it's even creating and writing the file and there is nothing in either my TextBox or TextBlock. :(

I got the code from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185401.aspx

Code to write the file:

```
private async void submitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //WRITE THE TICKET TO A LOCAL DATABASE (txt)//

        //Create the text file to hold the data
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile ticketsFile =
            await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("tickets.txt",
                Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        //Write data to the file
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(ticketsFile, "Swift as a shadow");
    }
```

Code to read the file in a TextBox:

```
private async void viewTickets_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile ticketsFile =
            await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("tickets.txt");

        string savedTickets = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(ticketsFile);

        viewTickets.Text = savedTickets; 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure these events are being fired? Because everything else seems to be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure... I don't even know if it's writing the text file. :( And which event handlers should I use for the text box to automatically read the file?

Comment: Well then set the breakpoints and debug your code. When you want to read the file?

Comment: OK so it does work, looks like you need to type in the TextBox before anything shows. I want the TextBox to display the code without any user interaction if that's possible...

Comment: You want to read the file immediately after clicking on a button? I don't understand when you exactly want to read and show it.

Comment: So I have a textbox which contains the contents of the text file. As soon as the text file is written, I want the contents of it to be visible in the textbox without having to click/tap on it or anything...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, the only problem is it doesn't get executed. When you click on the `button` your file is created. But you don't type anything in the `textbox` so you never read the file.

I think you want to read it immediately after writing it. Put your `Read` file code right after the `Write` code:

```
private async void submitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //WRITE THE TICKET TO A LOCAL DATABASE (txt)//

    //Create the text file to hold the data
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile ticketsFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("tickets.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    //Write data to the file
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(ticketsFile, "Swift as a shadow");

    //read file
    string savedTickets = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(ticketsFile);

    viewTickets.Text = savedTickets;
}
```

and remove the `viewTickets_TextChanged` event handler.

Comment: Is this local file saved immediately in the app? If not (which I'm guessing) how to save it, so I can retrieve it next time I enter the app?

Comment: @LayaleMatta When you save a file, the main purpose is to read it later. So obviously you can read it next time you enter the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task WriteToDictionaryAsync(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, StorageFile binarySourceFile)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(binarySourceFile.Path))
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            // Put count.
            writer.Write(dictionary.Count);
            // Write pairs.
            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                writer.Write(pair.Key);
                writer.Write(pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    public async void WriteToDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, StorageFile binarySourceFile)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(binarySourceFile.Path))
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            // Put count.
            writer.Write(dictionary.Count);
            // Write pairs.
            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                writer.Write(pair.Key);
                writer.Write(pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> ReadDictionaryAsync(StorageFile binarySourceFile)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(binarySourceFile.Path))
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            // Get count.
            int count = reader.ReadInt32();
            // Read in all pairs.
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string key = reader.ReadString();
                string value = reader.ReadString();
                result[key] = value;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ReadDictionary(StorageFile binarySourceFile)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(binarySourceFile.Path))
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            // Get count.
            int count = reader.ReadInt32();
            // Read in all pairs.
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string key = reader.ReadString();
                string value = reader.ReadString();
                result[key] = value;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

//Create bin File
var binarySourceFile = await StorageData.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("binFile" + ".bin", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);