# UWP Windows 10 C# Writing data to a new line in .txt file

Tags: c#, windows, text, universal

Hi I'm currently developing a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) App for Windows 10 but have come across an issue. I'm having trouble figuring out how to write data on a new line in a txt file as the data I write just overwrites the data on the first line. Would appreciate any help! Cheers.

The write/read code is below which I got from [Writing to and reading from a text file - C# Windows Universal Platform App Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533593/writing-to-and-reading-from-a-text-file-c-sharp-windows-universal-platform-app/34534120#34534120?newreg=3d53a41b48b248ad9fb36cd1a1ba1420)

```cs
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create the text file to hold the data
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile ticketsFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("tickets.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        string ingredients = IngredientBox.Text;
        //Write data to the file
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(ticketsFile, ingredients);

        //read file
        string savedTickets = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(ticketsFile);
        var path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path;

        StepsBox.Text = path;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711453/appending-text-to-file-windows-store-apps-windows-rt?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Cheers! Saved me a lot of ache!